# Unable to make swagger doc ui/api public in spring boot security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to add `swagger` to my existing application. I have added the following dependencies :

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Now the API `/swagger-ui/` and `/v2/api-docs` is working fine. I am developing the application in REST API. The API's are working fine from `POST man` when i am sending JWT Token with them. They are not working in browser.

To make them working in browser, i have added the URL's in spring security permit all. But it is still not working in browser.

**Spring Security Config:**

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        .............
                        "/v2/api-docs",
                        "/swagger-ui.html")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter())
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager())).sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().cors();

    }
```

How can i make those API's public?

Answer (score 0):

try using security config

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            "/healthz"
    };
    
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make public more urls than just those two.

Springfox documentation states to allow the following urls

```
.antMatchers(
          HttpMethod.GET,
          "/v2/api-docs",
          "/swagger-resources/**",
          "/swagger-ui.html**",
          "/webjars/**",
          "favicon.ico"
        ).permitAll()
```

or to ignore them:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
      .antMatchers(
        "/v2/api-docs",
        "/swagger-resources/**",
        "/swagger-ui.html**",
        "/webjars/**");
  }
}
```

source: https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/